# How to print gradient values for a particular layer of my tensorflow model?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets, gradient-descent, gradienttape

I am training a model in TensorFlow 2.3

I want to see the value of gradients for different layers of my model.

I know how to access the layers of my model.

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    lstm = model(song_emb_inp=song_emb_id_x_batch,
                 time_bucket_emb_inp=time_bucket_emb_id_x_batch,
                 training=True)
    
    loss = compute_loss(model, song_emb_id_y_batch, lstm)   
    
grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)

for var, g in zip(model.trainable_variables, grads):
    print(f'{var.name}, shape: {g.shape}')
```

It gives the following output-

[image]

How do I print the gradient values for all these trainable layers?

Answer (score 1):

You already have the gradients (g in your code)
If you want to print the gradients you can do `print(g)` instead of `print(g.shape)`

Example below (using your code)

```
model = ...
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    output = model(x)
    loss = compute_loss(output, y)   

grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)

for var, g in zip(model.trainable_variables, grads):
    # in this loop g is the gradient of each layer
    print(f'{var.name}, shape: {g.shape}')
    print("gradients..")
    print(g)
```